# Apple Macbook Air Optimisation

Tags: macbook

I have a MacbookAir6,1 (2013/14) model and with elementaryOS Luna it does not shutdown - just hangs on the eOS splash screen so I have to force off.

Also, it runs hot quite easily. Do you know of any optimisations out there specifically for MacBookAir or Macbook's that I can run to make it run cooler?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I installed this again yesterday alongside my current main distro of Lubuntu and I have noticed the shutdown issue is no longer there so maybe resolved and bundled in the ISO or an update to the OS.

Thanks, I have does the first few steps of the guide just not the one after installing Thermalds which involves a lot of tweaking (too much tweaking scares me). I'll see how it runs and let you know if input the rest.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post install on a MacBook Air for various distros.

https://github.com/1Claude/linux_on_Macbook_Air